# When will if(!ptr_name) be true?

Tags: c, pointers

Below code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int is_legal(char* name)
{
   if(!name)
        return -1;
   else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        char* test_name='\0';
        printf("is legal return value : %d\n",is_legal(test_name));
return 0;
}
```

gave me the result :

```
is legal return value : -1
```

If assign a string to `test_name`, it gives me a return value zero which indeed means that `if(!name)` is false.

Is there any scenario, other than assigning `test_name` to `'\0'`, where I get `if(!name)` as true.

Is `if(!name)` a standard practice to check if a string is empty?

Comment: `\0` is not NULL. Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Try `test_name = NULL;` instead.  Don't you get any warnings from the compiler?

Comment: gcc `-Wall` didn't give me any warning for both cases (`\0` & `NULL`)

Comment: Always use `1`/`0` for true/false! Better use the standard-type `_Bool`/`bool` and the corresponding constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing 2 things: NULL pointer and string nul `\0` termination.

```
char * nonExistent = NULL;  // Pointer doesn't point to string
char * emptyString = "";    // Pointer points to empty string (array with one element \0)
is_legal(nonExistent); // Returns -1
is_legal(emptyString); // Returns 0
```

In your case `\0` is integer constant `0`, which is interpreted as NULL pointer when assigned to pointer. So it works, but is incorrect.

Typical way to test if string is not NULL and non empty is this:

```
char * str = ...
if(str && *str) { // First check is for NULL pointer, seconds tests for \0 in first element of string
    printf("String exists and is not empty");
```

Comment: Thanks pal. Appreciate the clean solution you provided with neat comments, so a +1 too.. :)

Answer (score 2):

When a pointer is cast into a boolean, the result is:

- false (0) if the pointer is NULL
- true otherwise

Applying the boolean not operator (`!`) to a pointer forces the cast into boolean and then inverses the resulting value.

Besides, a `char*` pointer pointing at an empty string `""` **is not** a NULL pointer.

In your test, you have set `char* test_name = '\0';` which means  `char* test_name = 0;` and since NULL = 0 (for most but not all compilers), you have `test_name` is a NULL pointer.

On the other hand, if you made `char* test_name = "\0";` (with double-quotes), the result would be a pointer pointing at an empty string, but still, the pointer `test_name` itself is not a NULL pointer.

To check whether a char* pointer is valid and also that the string pointed-to is not empty, you can do this:

```
`if(test_name && *test_name)` // valid pointer and non-empty string
```

or negatively:

```
if((test_name == NULL) || (*test_name == '\0')) // invalid pointer or empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(!name)` tends to check if `(!0)` in your case which is `if(1)` which is true.

And

`char* test_name='\0';`

should be

`char* test_name=NULL;`

> Is there any scenario, other than assigning test_name to '\0', where I get if(!name) as true.

`name` has to be `non zero` if you want to enter into `if` condition

> Is if(!name) a standard practice to check if a string is empty?

No. It is just a way to check if a string is empty.

Comment: Appreciate the time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function `is_legal()` will return `-1` if `name` is the NULL pointer.   `if (!name)` is functionally equivalent to `if (name == 0)`.

The thing is, a null pointer can be formed by converting an integral value of zero into a pointer.   The character `\0` is an integral value with numeric value of zero, so

```
char* test_name='\0';
```

will initialise `test_name` to the null pointer.  Which explains the output you are seeing.

Most compilers will warn about doing that (assuming you configure your compiler to maximise warning levels) since converting a value of type `char` (the value `\0`) into a pointer is a suspicious act.